# How to add github account to maven without storing plaintext password

Tags: maven, github, repository

Alright, so I'm trying to create my own GitHub maven repository for one of my projects. I looked up a tutorial on how to do this and part of it was adding my GitHub account to my maven configuration file. Apparently, when adding it it should look like this:

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>github</id>
      <username>YOUR-GITHUB-USERNAME</username>
      <password>YOUR-GITHUB-PASSWORD</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

While this is all cool and dandy, I feel really uncomfortable having my GitHub password stored in plain-text somewhere on my machine. Is there any other way I can connect my GitHub account to maven?

Comment: This question has nothing to so with java.  Untagging appropriately.

Comment: I would recommend to read the encryption of passwords with Maven: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html

Comment: @JoeC Apologies about that Java tag, I added it because Maven is normally used with Java and SO recommended for me to use it :P

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks! I wasn't able to get it working [due to a glitch in the latest version](https://github.com/github/maven-plugins/issues/55) but once it's fixed I'll know how to do it :)

Comment: So you are using maven-site? I'm using maven site plugin etc. with GitHub without any issue